# red5chat Support Android for Video Chat

Tags: videochat

Have any idea about red5chat support with Android regarding Video Chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since red5chat design using Action Script and uptill now b4 release of Android 2.2 ,Action Script not supported by Android.

Now Android 2.2 have support for Action Script.